# sudo --set-home decide based on command

Tags: linux, sudo, sudoers

I was wondering if there is a way to make `sudo` set the `--set-home` flag based on the command being executed.

e.g. in most cases I do not want the `--set-home` flag to be set, but for `npm`, I want it to be set.

I read though the quite exhaustive `sudoers` manpage but was unable to anwer this question myself.

Comment: Why don't you simply create a BASH alias to run npm with the right settings? Or write a BASH script.

Comment: I do not need to run npm as root all the time, just sometimes.

Comment: Even more reason to create an alias or script, just run that when you want it. Far easier than faffing with SUDO.